# Chrome start more drivers error with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm having a problem with selenium python in Google Chrome, The code is this:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\mcara\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path="C:\\Users\\mcara\\PycharmProjects\\Instagramm\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe")
driver_2 = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path="C:\\Users\\mcara\\PycharmProjects\\Instagramm\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver_2.set_page_load_timeout(30)
actions = ActionChains(driver)



driver.maximize_window()
driver_2.maximize_window()


driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
```

The code works fine at the start, it loads the Default account, Opens the pages and maximize them. But when it has to go at the url its code stops, after it gives this error:

> ```
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
> (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT
> ```
>
> 10.0.17134 x86_64)

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Why are you trying to start 2 chrome drivers here? Its possible the second chrome driver instance is crashing the first one and that is why you are getting this error.

Comment: yes thanks, i tried now with only 1 driver and it works, how i can start the second driver in the same code with the same profile? becouse i need too work with 2 drivers at the same time

Answer (score 0):

your creates a single profile, but you are attempting to share it between 2 driver instances.  That won't work.